# Tropical Geometry and Quantization

Tags: resource-recommendations, algebraic-geometry, deformation-quantization

Recently I saw [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83624/why-tropical-geometry) posted on Math Overflow asking about the motivations behind tropical geometry. The OP mentions that tropical geometry can be viewed as the classical limit of regular algebraic geometry. Are there any references regarding this topic? As far as I know, the only application of tropical geometry to physics is in mirror symmetry. However, this question seems to imply that quantization can be described by tropical geometry. I would appreciate any guidance on this topic.

Comment: No, the question does not necessarily imply that, because the mathematicians have abstracted the term "quantization" to mean a special kind of *deformation* of algebras and groups as it occurs, for example, in [deformation quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_quantization). This quantization stuff, like [quantum cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cohomology) is called quantum because it arose originally in quantum physics, but is now studied in its own right and need not have connections to physics in every case.